# show json result that instagram posted

Tags: php, jquery, json, ajax

I'm Trying to give access token from Instagram api,I send my data with ajax in laravel and I give access_token in json.
my view that show ajax jquery is:

```
  var $data;
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("button").click(function(){
            $.ajax({

                method: 'POST',
                url:'https://api.instagram.com/oauth/access_token',
                headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'},
                data: {client_id: "d52c34",client_secret:"<MY client_secret HERE>",
                    grant_type:"authorization_code", redirect_uri:"http://ie-asemi.ir/laravel/public/instagram/test",
                    dataType:"json",
                    processData: true,
                    code:"{{$code}}"},
                dataType:"json",
                contentType: 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'

        });
    });


</script>
```

How can I get json result in this page?[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jw7ss.png)

I add done function anythings changed,[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bM3d0.png)

Comment: You use `.done()` to return the data response. If it is JSON is can be easily accessed. [See the examples in the docs here.](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)

Comment: Careful when copying and pasting code that contains your `client_secret`

Comment: @samiles I'm new in jquery can you help me more?

Comment: @ThrowingSpoon Ok thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the `done` method of ajax to get the response

```
var $data;
$(document).ready(function(){
     $("button").click(function(){
         $.ajax({
            method: 'POST',
            url:'https://api.instagram.com/oauth/access_token',
            headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'},
            data: {client_id: "d52c34",client_secret:"a84124d81947347fd35e9aef8",
            grant_type:"authorization_code", redirect_uri:"http://ie-asemi.ir/laravel/public/instagram/test",
            dataType:"json",
            processData: true,
            code:"{{$code}}"},
            dataType:"json",
            contentType: 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
      }).done(function(response) {
            console.log(response)
      });
});
</script>
```

Comment: I'm checking this code but json result don't show for me

Comment: you are checking into console, right? what does the console prints....may be any error?